# Is there a way to prevent a file from being deleted?

Tags: windows, ntfs

I have a file on NTFS that holds accumulated information that will take forever to recreate. I marked it as 'archive' and 'system', so that it would not be obvious to notice or mishandle, but what I really want is to put some kind of lock on it, so that deleting it would only be possible when providing a password or fulfilling some other condition.

Is there a tool that can help me? perhaps some hidden Windows feature?

Comment: Is it not possible to simply make a backup of the file?

Comment: It is simple, and I really should do this. I guess because the file is updated at least once a day I'm more worried about it being deleted between backups.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under NTFS you can alter the access rights for users and groups either at a folder level or at a file level.

Right click on a file or folder and go to the security tab. You can then remove users rights for deleting / modifying a file. Ensure you leave the administrator and administrators full rights. Also, if it on a domain ensure that both the local administrator and domain administrators have full access rights.

Comment: Just remember that there is no way to prevent a file from being deleted by ALL users - otherwise, you'd never be able to delete the file! Access permissions are best, but if you're logged on as the user who has permission to delete the files - you WILL be able to delete them, with nothing more than the standard "are you sure" Windows prompt.

Answer (score 13):

Just remove modify permissions from anyone but the user account that creates the file. This kind of thing is exactly what NTFS rights are for.

Comment: can you elaborate on this please?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would elaborate on "remove modify permissions". Just right-click the file and change the permissions accordingly.

Comment: Did you try this? Denying modify on the file has no effect, because the folder it's in is still writeable, so the file can be moved (to the Recycle Bin).

Answer (score 13):

"accumulated information that will take forever to recreate" - the time to prepare a backup / restore procedure is **right now**. Don't wait until the file is somehow deleted or overwritten, or the disk fails. A proper backup strategy with proven (and tested) restore capability is a must.

Comment: So true... and I'm on my way to do just that :-) Still, is there a way to prevent the file from being deleted?

Comment: +1: For testing. Without confidence it can be recovered, the backup is just hope.

Comment: "write only" backups can be disappointing, but can help if you need a short backup time ;-)

Comment: I know backups are nice and all... But how do they prevent a file from being deleted (since this is what the OP is actually asking for)?

Comment: A backup doesn't prevent the file from being deleted, obviously, but if a file is truly that critical, a backup is equally so.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a full logical protection, since Deny takes precedence on Allow, File **Properties** > **Security** tab > **Advanced** Security Setting , **Deny** to **Everybody** the **delete** right on this file.

Again, a full backup of this file is in order.